How to achieve this stacked thin transparent sheets shading in cycles?
I tried modeling an individual card with an array modifier applied, but applying a transparent shader to it only results to black (seems like it requires a lot of light bounces?). Then I tried modeling a solid one. I tried playing with the SSS, transparency, and volumetrics, but I cant get the result I want.


